# Android List view

Tags: android, list, view

Is there any way to customize listview in android app development so that I can display few items in a curved/elleptical/cylindrical view.
Need to display a bunch of item in a scrollable view on top but the items are not in a straight line but as if placed on a symmetric curve???

I want to have a list view like this image
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/listview.png/

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. You probably should add image that shows what you mean.

Comment: yes if what you mean is some 3D effect as the first answer points out that is what you will have to do, if that is not it please try to describe better what you want to achieve

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/listview.png/   this is how i was xpecting

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want/need a custom made list widget. You can probably accomplish what you're looking for if you dive into [3D with OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)

This cannot be done with the flip of a switch, but if you must have it, anything is possible.

As a starting point you could also look at the source for `ListView`

Comment: imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/listview.png this is how i was xpecting

Comment: Like I said, you're going to have to work the graphics in a custom way. That's why I mentioned getting familiar with OpenGL. There is no stock widget in the Android SDK that does what you're wanting.